# how to get rc shell to read .rcrc on startup on ubuntu?

Tags: shell, login

I am trying to use [rc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc) as my login shell in Ubuntu (using chsh). I noticed that it does not read $HOME/.rcrc file on startup. The documentation says that if invoked as a login shell with either *argv[0] == '-' or with -l flag, it reads the .rcrc file, and I can verify that by executing it directly by `$ rc -l`. or from zsh `ARGV0=-rc /usr/bin/rc`.

However when executed on login, it does not read the .rcrc file, and ps output indicates that the shell name is just "rc" not "-rc". Thus my question is, how to get /usr/bin/rc to read .rcrc at startup? and why is ubuntu not prefixing "-" to the shell? Is there a different way to detect the shell is a login shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux terminal emulators on the GUI do not usually open login shells by default as opposed to e.g. OS X's Terminal.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and log in on the command line, you'll have a login shell whose `.rcrc` commands will be executed.

---

In Ubuntu's Terminal, go to *Edit » Profile Preferences » Title and Command » Run command as a login shell*.

Alternatively, your terminal emulator might support execution of an arbitrary command. Use `/usr/bin/rc -l`.

---

You can also create a short script that simply launches `rc` as a login shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec -l /usr/bin/rc "$@"
```

This will start `bash` to execute the script, and the script replaces it completely with `rc` invoked as a login shell (`-l` argument), plus all other arguments to this script. You could also add the `-c` argument to sanitize the environment.

Save as `/usr/bin/rcl`, make executable, and add a corresponding entry to `/etc/shells`.

Comment: thanks, so are there any solutions for rc shell to read a user's initialization file (like .rcrc)? What do I do if I want to set the prompt in rc?

Comment: Did you read the last paragraph, I.e. the actual answer? Do that and it'll load rcrc.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does not help me because :- I do not use gnome-terminal (my question was about generic shell and not on a specific emulator). I was hoping for an /etc/passwd based solution. I was able to work around my problem using a wrapper script. But thank you for your answer. It confirmed what I suspected (in other unixes like solaris, the same thing works).

Comment: @blufox Most Terminals should allow execution of specific commands instead of the default shell. `/usr/bin/rc -l` would work in your case. Of course, this'll circumvent `/etc/passwd`/`chsh`. // You could also, of course, write a one-line script that just runs `/usr/bin/rc -l`, save it to `/usr/bin/rcl`, make it executable and add it to `/etc/shells`. Instant new shell!

Comment: xterm doesn't :), and I used the same solution - a wrapper.